# Laravel login and register forms on the same page in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

In laravel 8 how can i do login registration in same page , Problem is in both form email and password are same . valiadation error shows in both form .

Thanks in advance

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, you need to add your code, what you tried, what is the problem, etc.

Comment: Povilas Korop of Laravel Daily has written an article about this https://laraveldaily.com/laravel-login-and-register-forms-on-the-same-page/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have multiple forms with the same input names on one page you need to take a look at **[named error bags](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#named-error-bags)**.

If you are using `FormRequests`, it's quite easy. You can set a custom `ErrorBag` on the specific `FormRequest`.

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class LoginFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected $errorBag = 'loginForm';
}
```

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class RegisterFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected $errorBag = 'registerForm';
}
```

Earlier you have been used to use something like this in your blade files:

```html
<div>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</div>
```

This uses the default ErrorBag. But in our case, we have overwritten the bag with our custom ones. The syntax changes a little bit if you want to access them. Here's how.

```html
<div>{{ $errors->loginForm->first('email') }}</div>
<div>{{ $errors->registerForm->first('email') }}</div>
```